# Codeigniter index.php breaking image paths

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

When I don't edit my `.htaccess` file, my image path reads something like: `http://this.website.com/codeigniter/inc/images/logo.jpg`.

However, as soon as I add this code into the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

(to remove the `index.php` from the URL), I get 404 error, even with the exact same path.

How do I remove `index.php` and still have access to my images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

The two new `RewriteCond`itions would exclude existing directories and files (and so images) from redirection.

Comment: EDIT! This works perfectly! Just needed some time to update. Thanks for your help!